# Limit as n-> infinity of Integral of Gaussian Multiplied by Polynomial of Order n

Tags: limits, gaussian-integral

Can anyone tell me the result of the following limit or, at least, if it converges (n integer)?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2n}e^{({-1/2})ax^2}dx$$ I believe the integral evaluates to $\sqrt{(2\pi/a)}\dfrac{(2n)!}{(2a)^nn!}$

Thanks.

Comment: if I dont did any mistake I have that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n}e^{-\frac{ax^2}{2}}\mathrm dx=\sqrt{2\pi}a^{1/2-n}(2n-1)!!$$ what is not convergent when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @ masacroso: Thank you Masacroso. Are you saying that the limit of the expression on the right of your equation, as n approaches infinity, does not converge? Could you please tell me how do you go about proving that?

Answer (score 2):

Let $I_n$ be the integral. Then

$$I_n > \int_2^\infty 2^{2n} e^{(-1/2) a x^2} dx\to \infty. $$

Comment: Very simple and elegant solution. In more details:  $$2^{2n}\cdot \underbrace{\int_2^\infty e^{(-1/2) a x^2} dx}_{\text{const}}\to \infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

With the change of variable $ax^2/2=t$ we have that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n}e^{-\frac{ax^2}2}\mathrm dx=2\left(\frac2a\right)^{n-1/2}\int_0^\infty t^{n-1/2}e^{-t}\mathrm dt=2\left(\frac2a\right)^{n-1/2}\Gamma(n+1/n)$$

Now, by the reflection formula $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$ and the formula $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$ we knows that $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt\pi$, and by induction

$$\Gamma(n+1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}$$

where $(2n-1)!!:=1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots(2n-1)$. Then, rearranging all, we finally have that

$$I_n(a):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n}e^{-\frac{ax^2}{2}}\mathrm dx=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}a}\cdot\frac{(2n-1)!!}{a^n}$$

but observe, by the archimedean principle of $\Bbb R$, that exist some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $N>a$ for any (fixed) $a\in\Bbb R$. Then

$$\frac{(2m-1)!!}{a^{m+1}}=\frac{(2(m-1)-1)!!}{a^m}\cdot\frac{2m-1}{a}$$

where $(2m-1)/a>1$ if $m\ge N$. Then, by an induction argument, we can see that $$|I(a)|:=\lim_{n\to\infty}|I_n(a)|=\infty,\quad a\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$$

For $a\in\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R$ the limit is not defined, notice that if we define $a=re^{i\theta}$ then $a^n=r^n\cdot e^{in\theta}$, and the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}r^n\cdot e^{in\theta}=\lim_{n\to\infty}r^n\cdot (\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta))$$ doesnt exists.

Comment: I am not a mathematician and so I hope this question makes sense, but does the limit diverge to infinity or does it just oscillate and not actually approach anything?

Comment: @David the absolute value of the limit is infinity but the limit itself goes to infinity if $a>0$, in other cases it oscillates to infinity and minus infinity, or if $a$ have some imaginary part then it oscillates between infinite number of infinities. When a limit converge to more than one point we says that the limit doesnt exists. The set of points where the sequence converge is called the set of the limits points of the sequence. In any case infinity is not a point of $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ so we can just say that $I_n$ diverges in $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 0):

There are a multitude of ways to show that the limit does not exist, such as the one provided by @Masacroso . Here is another...
Let $W$ be a standard normal random variable. Then the given integral can be written as
\begin{align}
I_n = \sqrt\frac{2\pi}{a} \;\;\mathbb{E}[W^{2n}]
\end{align}
Using [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality), for any $k >0$, and in particular for $k=2$, we have $$\mathbb{E}[W^{2n}]  \geq k^{2n}\; \mathbb{P}(|W| \geq k ) = 4^{n}\; \mathbb{P}(|W| \geq 2 ) \longrightarrow \infty \textrm{ as } n \to \infty$$ since  $\mathbb{P}(|W| \geq 2 ) \in (0,1)$.